# DiscordJs Make reaction Bomb to comment

Tags: discord.js

I want to make a fun little code on the ideia of bombing a comment with reactions.

I know what i need but i dont know how to get it, i've really searched all around internet and i dont seem to find the necessary function.

I probably need: comment ID and channel ID so the command should need to be:
(prefix)command (args0 with channel id) (args1 with comment id) so it can reacti to the exact comment i want.

It should be possible to do this with a if function like

````
if (find(channel) and find(comment)){
    message.react('EMOJI')
}else {return message.reply('need to specify channelID and commentID')} ``` 

Thanks
````

Answer (score 0):

Your insight to the problem is absolutely correct, you may achieve this like so:

```js
let prefix = "!";
client.on("message", async (message) => {
if(message.author.bot) return 
 const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ')
if(message.content.toLowerCase() == "!bomb"){
if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Provide a channel ID")
if(!args[1]) return message.channel.send("Provide a message ID")
message.guild.channels.cache.get(`${args[0]}`).messages.fetch(`${args[1]}`).then(m => { m.react(""); });
message.channel.send("reacted");
}
})
```